Setup clang to point LLVM instead of bin?
Pardon if it's a beginners question... I'm trying to setup my clang and clang++ on my Mac Intel using brew.
For installing, I simply use brew install llvm libomp open-mpi.
Then I checked where it's pointing with which clang++ and which clang. The result I would get is /usr/bin/clang++ /usr/bin/clang.
I was recommended to use LLVM. So how can I make it to point to /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ and /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang instead of bin?
Thank you very much

PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH but you'll also need to follow the additional instructions provided by brew info llvm.

If you modify your PATH such that /usr/local/opt is ahead of /usr/bin it should fix your problem. It is along the lines of this stack overflow issue
Do remember to source your bash profile after you alter you PATH variable in there
